# Not able to save the CSV file in share point folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create one new csv file and save it in folder in sharepoint one drive

I have written the  VBA code in work book open event . the purpose of this macro is to track the usage metrics whenever any user open this file

But I am not able to see any file created in the folder after running the code without any error

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim UserName As String, TimeStamp As Variant, toolname As String
    Dim myLogFile As String, sLogBataBasePath As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer

    sLogBataBasePath = "//myteams.xyz.com/sites/Global Analytics - Respiratory/Working Documents/Data Cube/Usage Metrics"

    toolname = "ft"
        
    UserName = VBA.Environ("username")
    TimeStamp = VBA.Format(Now(), "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss")

    myLogFile = sLogBataBasePath & "/" & UserName & "_" & TimeStamp & ".csv"

    Open myLogFile For Output As #1
        Write #1, UserName,
        Write #1, toolname,
        Write #1, VBA.Format(Now(), "ddmmmyyyy hh:mm:ss")
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`, that's hiding the error.

Comment: Try replacing spaces in the URL with %20

Comment: I tried this but  still not working ...no file getting created

Comment: No error message when it runs?

Comment: No error message while running

Comment: Works for me but really slowly...

Comment: ..."really slowly" - 2-5 secs per write

Comment: Did anyone find a way? Thank you.